# Magento 2.4.2 How to disable MSI

Tags: magento2

Here I have solution how to disable for M.2.4 - but this solution  no work for M.2.4.2

Run the below command in your SSH to disable MSI in Magento 2.4.0

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryGraphQl
```

Comment: Interesting, You can also try to disable it from `/app/etc.config.php` file.

Answer (score 3):

I use the composer replace method which removes the packages completely from the vendor directory. A quick and easy way to fo this is run `composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory` as this has all the packages to remove already listed in it's composer file.

This will install the package from https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable MSI using two different methods.

1. Find all MSI modules in config.php file and set their values to 0 i.e disable them.
2. Run the below commands to disable MSI in Magento2 2.4.2:-

`php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension`

Finally, run the following commands:-

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

If you want to learn how to enable/disable MSI in different versions of Magento such as 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5 and learn more about MSI then please visit [HERE](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-magento-2-msimulti-source-inventory.html).

Comment: It's solved my issue. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I got below error 

Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface#0 /var/www/html/otc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command for Magento 2.4.3 version

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist
```

Answer (score 0):

the modules

```
Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct
```

are part of MSI?
disabling all other with this enabled i get the error

> main.CRITICAL: Error: Cannot instantiate interface
> Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\Data\StockItemConfigurationInterface
> in
> /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CLI command to disable all MSI modules in 2.4.4:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Inventory Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension
```

And I would say do not use -f (force) option in the command becuase it will help you to give you suggestion for dependent modules and any MSI module that we are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any DB table that needs to be removed as well? After removing MSI by "module: disable" I keep getting constant DB errors and "MySQL server has gone away: issues.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/209336)